# Review->Close popup Issue

Tags: bug, status-norepro, google-chrome, popups

I am facing weird issue with the Review->Close question popup, specifically for duplicate questions tab. I have a few screenshots explaining the issue.

Steps

1. In review, for any duplicate question, click on duplicate tab.
2. Scroll to the answer section.
3. Click on Close tab
4. Check screenshots for issue.

Sample1

[image]

Sample2

[image]

When I close this popup,

Sample1

[image]

Sample2

[image]

I have to scroll up/down so that the web page appears correctly again. Possible bug? I am using Google Chrome on MacOSX 10.8.5

---

This works correctly on Safari browser.

Comment: can't repro, do you still get this error?